# Codes works with the PHP on windows server but same not in linux

Tags: php, linux

The code below works fine with the windows server for php 8.0, but it does not load the DOM further on Linux server with same php version,

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label>User: </label>
    <select class="form-control select2 user_cal" type="text" name="user_holidays[]" id="users_filter" data-placeholder="Select User.." multiple>
        <?php
        echo "<option value=''>--</option>";
        $sql_qry_bdg = "select Distinct d.Badge,d.First_Name,d.Last_Name,(select count(*) from Calend where to_date(booked_date,'YYYY/MM/DD') > TO_DATE('" . $last_year_sunday . "','YYYY/MM/DD') and to_date(booked_date,'YYYY/MM/DD') < TO_DATE('" . $next_year_sunday . "','YYYY/MM/DD') and IS_ACTIVE='Y' and User_Badge=D.Badge) as count from Dir d
                                                          where  d.type !='Agency'";

        foreach ($conn->query($sql_qry_bdg) as $row) {
            //$manu = $row['FULLNAME'];
            echo "<option value='" . $row['BADGE'] . "'";
            if (in_array($row['BADGE'], $_POST['user_holidays'])) {
                echo " selected ";
            }
            echo ">" . $row['BADGE'] . " - " . $row['FIRST_NAME'] . " " . $row['LAST_NAME'] . " (" . $row['COUNT'] . ")</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help

Thank You

Comment: What exactly is happening? Does the code stop here, or does it just not show any values. View the source in the browser and see if there are any error messages showing. Double-check the database on the server to make sure the data you think is there, and try running the query directly in the database.

Comment: what does "does not load the DOM further" mean exactly? Are you getting an error from PHP? It's unclear what the problem is. None of the code you've shown here is dependent on or specific to any operating system. At a guess, if you've changed environment, the most likely issue within what you've provided is probably something preventing the SQL query from being executed. But if that's the case you should get an error about it (assuming you've enabled error logging appropriately).

Comment: code stops here in the linux server, it runs if I comment the if part of the code, but it works perfectly fine in windows server

Comment: "stops" means what exactly? If the code "stops" you should get an error. What exact output are you getting?

Comment: Stop means the on the browser it does not load, and also does not give any error message

Comment: It may not be showing any *visible* error messages, considering you're in and out of tags here. Open up source in the browser and go to the bottom. What does it show?

Comment: "it" being what? The whole page? Or just part of the output is missing? Again, you're being vague. Remember that we cannot see your screen, run your code, or read your mind, and that in programming small details are important. Have you checked the PHP error log file for errors? Have you actually got PHP error logging set up on this new server? And/or have you checked the _raw_ output in your browser's View Source feature as mentioned above? You haven't confirmed if you've done any of these things.

Comment: I think you should turn on the error display on linux server, I bet it can be some libraries missing/not the same version

Comment: Try adding the following to the top of your PHP script and update with the exact errors you are getting:



    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: I got this error after adding ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);  Warning: Undefined array key "user_holidays"

Comment: Well, that suggests you didn't submit a value for that field in your $_POST array. Which is something which has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: So, you are using $_POST["user_holidays"], but you didn't make sure that key is set in $_POST first.

Comment: But I am not getting that error in windows server and it works but getting that error in linux

Comment: It still has nothing to do with the actual operating system though. You need to properly debug your code (probably in the frontend) and find out why nothing was submitted for that value when you send the data to PHP (e.g. if it's from a form submission or ajax request or whatever). _Perhaps_ it relates to some other issue in your environment somehow which led to this scenario, or perhaps you deployed a different version of the code to this server or something like that. But there's certainly no magic answer we can give you "because it's Linux". Missing POST data is not an O/S-level issue.

Comment: The only real differences when it comes to PHP pages on Linux vs Windows are file paths and case sensitivity -- Windows is not case sensitive, Linux is. Unless the issue is one of those two, then the OS is a symptom, not a cause. It could be a difference in the PHP version or settings, though. If this page can be accessed via GET, then you need to make sure that `$_POST` exists before you try to access any values inside it.

Comment: If this page can be accessed via GET, then try `if(array_key_exists('user_holidays', $_POST) && in_array($row['BADGE'], $_POST['user_holidays']))`

Comment: No problem. So did you solve it then? Please add an Answer below and show everyone how it was fixed.